# Using crosstab and pivot

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a table like so -

| MonthID | PlanType | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202004 | Medicare | 1582 |
| 202004 | Medicaid | 6820 |
| 201904 | Medicare | 3875 |
| 201904 | Other | 12598 |
| 201905 | Other | 41817 |
| 201905 | Medicare | 16886 |
| 201905 | Medicaid | 20877 |

I want to use pivot to get this output -

| Month | Medicare | Other | Medicaid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201905 | 16886 | 41817 | 20877 |
| 201904 | 3875 | 12598 |  |
| 202004 | 1582 |  | 6820 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filtered aggregation:

```
select month, 
       sum(count) filter (where plantype = 'Medicare') as medicare,
       sum(count) filter (where plantype = 'Medicaid') as medicaid,
       sum(count) filter (where plantype = 'Other') as other
from the_table
group by month;
```